# How do I determine how much rent I could charge for a property or location?

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property

I am interested in investing in property.  How do I go about figuring out the `rent-ability` of any given property?  As in how do I figure out how much rent a property could get potentially on average per month for example?

For example, for any given area, how do I figure out the average rental rate.

This question is regarding apartments/houses/homes etc.  Not businesses.

Comment: Do you mean an apartment or home? VS a business?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This may not be entirely scientific, but as a landlord my usual approach is just to do a search for rental properties on [Craigslist](http://london.craigslist.co.uk/) for comparable homes in the neighborhood. There are all kinds of formulas professional property managers use, but in the end these listings are the ones you are going to be competing with for tenants.

Also, it isn't super accurate, but online services like [Zillow.com](http://www.zillow.com) can give you some numbers for rental houses that include those that aren't currently advertising.

Comment: In the US, I'd use realtor.com before craigslist or zillow.com, but I definitely think this is where to start.  You're basically doing your own personal comparative market analysis (CMA) that a realtor would do if you hired them.  Getting a realtor's opinion wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the property websites to get an idea of how much, the property in question, could yield as rent. Most give a range and you can get a good idea of it.

[Just one example from zoopla](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/property/81-pathfield-road/london/sw16-5pa/23338387).

Likewise you can refer mouseprice or rightmove and get yourself an idea. Property websites do a lot of data crunching to do an update, but their figure is only a guide.

Answer (score 4):

Zoopla may not always accurately reflect the market price. Your best bet is to get a quote for local registered) letting agents. That way you know you are close to the real market value.

Also, these quotes may come into handy if you have a mortgage on the property. Since most banks will require you to provide proof of rent figures you are projecting by sending in official quotes.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Agreed. Letting agents have a vested interest in letting out properties at the maximum price that the market will support. Too high, and no-one will rent it; too low, and they get less commission (and you get less rent). Also, ask a few lettings agents; hopefully you will get similar numbers from them.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to find the rates of rental prices is to look what other landlords are charging for similar properties in your area. The proper investigation of property rental market should be make by using property listing platforms.

The other method is online rent calculator. There are a bunch of them on the Web. Briefly speaking, the rent calculator uses industry data to look at the typical rent you might expect from a property in a post code.

Remember that the rent you charge has to be at least equal to the cost of your monthly mortgage bill. When you’re deciding what to charge, don’t forget to factor in an estimate of repair costs, taxes, homeowners association fees and insurance.